# Anaconda reinstall did not update base directory

Tags: anaconda, radix, navigator, reinstall

I am having an issue running a re-installed version of Anaconda. When I first installed it, I (stupidly) ignored the warning regarding the default directory having a space in the path (C:\Users\Firstname Lastname\Anaconda). I am now attempting to reinstall Anaconda directly in a C:\Anaconda directory, but when I do, I run into the following:

1. Anaconda Navigator still appears to consider the old directory as the base. When I go to Environments->Base(root)->Open Terminal is still shows the previous directory.
2. None of the applications in the Home page of the Anaconda Navigator respond, again presumably because of the mismatch between currently-installed directory and where the program for some reason persists the installed content is located.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.